# Does someone have to retake the shahada after deliberately eating pork?

Tags: pork, shahada

I know someone who purposely ate pork on two or three occasions. He asked me whether he is still considered Muslim. I told him yes, and to ask for forgiveness. He was wondering does he have to retake his shahadah.

Does someone have to retake the shahada after deliberately eating pork?

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not he needs to, it won't hurt if he does it anyway. It's just a matter of saying two lines and meaning them in your heart. Tell him to say it anyway, just in case, although this isn't really a matter of "if he doesn't say it he's not a muslim".

The best he can do is repent to Allah (SWT), and InShaAllah he will be forgiven.